# how to generate .xap file using Visual Studio Team Services and how to automate the build generation process

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I want to automate the bulid generation process(.xap or .appx). I have come across Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) and found that we can do that.

I am facing two problems.

1. How to add my existing github repositories to my vs online server.
2. How to generate the .xap file and where can i find that file (if it is generated).

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build system in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly VSO) to build code from GitHub.  Here is a tutorial and connecting your GitHub account to Team Services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/define/repository#GitHub

Then you can create a build definition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/vs/define-build

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can u pls tell me where can i find the generated .xap file once the build got succeeded.

Comment: Open the completed build and there is an Artifacts link that will have all the compiled outputs.